# Unique values in each of the columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to get the number of unique values in each of the columns of a data frame.
Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,2), v2 = c("a","a","b","b"))
```

then it should return that there are 3 distinct values for v1, and 2 for v2.

I tried unique(DF), but it does not work as each rows are different.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Or using `unique`:

```
rapply(DF,function(x)length(unique(x)))
v1 v2 
 3  2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
sapply(DF, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach:

```
> lapply(DF, function(x) length(table(x)))
$v1
[1] 3

$v2
[1] 2
```

This basically tabulates the unique values per column. Using `length` on that tells you the number. Removing `length` will show you the actual table of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness: Since CRAN version 1.9.6 of 19 Sep 2015, the `data.table` package includes the helper function `uniqueN()` which saves us from writing

`function(x) length(unique(x))`

when calling one of the siblings of `apply()`:

```
sapply(DF, data.table::uniqueN)
```

> ```
> v1 v2 
>  3  2
> ```

Note that neither the `data.table` package needs to be loaded nor `DF` coerced to class `data.table` in order to use `uniqueN()`, here.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr (>=1.0.0 - june 2020)`:

```
DF %>% summarize_all(n_distinct)

  v1 v2
1  3  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a function like this would give you what you are looking for. This also shows the unique values, in addition to how many NA's there are in each dataframe's columns. Simply plug in your dataframe, and you are good to go.

```
totaluniquevals <- function(df) {
  x <<- data.frame("Row Name"= numeric(0), "TotalUnique"=numeric(0), "IsNA"=numeric(0))
  result <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
  isnatotals <- sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

  #Now Create the Row names
  for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
    x[i,1] <<- (names(result[i]))
    x[i,2] <<- result[[i]]
    x[i,3] <<- isnatotals[[i]]

  }
  return(x)
}
```

Test:

```
DF <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,2), v2 = c("a","a","b","b"))
totaluniquevals(DF)
  Row.Name TotalUnique IsNA
1       v1           3    0
2       v2           2    0
```

You can then use unique on whatever column, to see what the specific unique values are.

> unique(DF$v2)
>   [1] a b
>   Levels: a b

Comment: Why are you using global assignment `<<-` for a temporay variable within a function? This will overwrite any object `x` defined outside of the function.

Comment: BTW, your function can be rewritten more concisely as `totaluniquevals <- function(df) data.frame(Row.Name = names(df), TotalUnique = sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))), IsNA = sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for getting an unique value for each variable:

```
length(unique(datasetname$variablename))
```

Answer (score -3):

This will give you unique values in DF dataframe of column 1.

```
unique(sc_data[,1])
```

Comment: The OP has asked: _I want to get the number of unique values in each of the columns of a data frame._ Your answer only returns the unique values of just one column, not even the number. So, it doesn't answer the question. Please, consider to remove your post.